# Can we use two strings in 'selectByVisibleText' method in Seleniumwebdriver

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I have a Situation where my String is getting merged with symbol '»' after running a script. So after detecting an element from Drop-down element i have to Select it only by visible Text but i have to add » before my String.

Is their any way to handle this?

Comment: Is the '»' present in the dropdown items or is it just attached to the first element that is selected ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one thing in such a case:

```
WebElement web = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select"));
List<WebElement> lst2 = web.findElements(By
        .xpath(".//option[contains(text(),'<yourText>')]"));
    for (WebElement option : lst2) {
    if (!option.isSelected()) {
        option.click();
    }
}
```

Hope this would help, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Vivek, Let me Try.

Comment: Hi rupesh...did it worked? If yes kindly accept else let me know any issues u had...thanks...

Comment: In your implementation for the Xpath of dropdown option i will have to pass my string value manually which i dont want to. Because in my script i am accepting this value only one time from user and storing that value in string variable.

Comment: Since you are storing the string in a variable, so u can pass that in the method as a parameter which contains the above script. So u DONT have to enter it manually. But can i know what u mean't by manually here? :O

Comment: In List<WebElement> lst2 = web.findElements(By
        .xpath(".//option[contains(text(),'<yourText>')]"));   ....I cannot pass my variable name  in <yourText> field i will have to pass my variable value.

Comment: `List<WebElement> lst2 = web.findElements(By.xpath(".//option[contains(text(),'" + str + "')]"));` have you tried it like this? Please try, you'll get your solution, cause this always works for me... 
P.S. here `str` is your variable..