# WebDriver C# - Selecting an item from a drop down list using partial text

Tags: c#, webdriver

I am writing a WebDriver test case in C# where I need to select an item in a drop down list.

The text on the dropdown will be a persons name followed by distance and capacity. The problem is that only the first section of the text displayed is known at runtime, i.e. the persons name. If this were a link I could click on it using the following fairly standard code:

```
driver.FindElements(By.Id("Name")).Click();
```

But alas it is not a link. I have copied the definition of the `SelectByText()` method from `SelectElement` class in `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI` below. Or more specifically the comments from the definition relating to substring/partial text matches in the `SelectByText()` method:

```
// Parameters:
//   text:
//     The text of the option to be selected. If an exact match is not found, this
//     method will perform a substring match.
```

I can't get the method to `perform a substring match`.

This is what I have tried. For example my HTML code is similar to this:

```
<select id="ddlTest">
   <option>Firstname Lastname - 35 miles - 50%</option>
</select>
```

I have tried the following C# Webdriver which didn't find the substring match I was expecting.

```
var selectList = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlTest"));
var options = new SelectElement(selectList);
options.SelectByText("Firstname Lastname");
```

And that is where the test fails as it couldn't find an element with the text `Firstname Lastname`.

How do I get this method to use the substring match it describes in the definition comments I copied above?

Comment: Never worked in C#..but hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130770/can-we-use-two-strings-in-selectbyvisibletext-method-in-seleniumwebdriver/27142826#27142826) helps you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
selectList.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("./option[starts-with(text(), '{0}')]", "Firstname Lastname"))).Click();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am getting an error with this line: "string does not contain a definition for format"

Any ideas?

Comment: @dmeehan try to capitalise Format method. I was typing of the top of my head and typoed, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but should work for you

```
By byXpath = By.XPath("//select[@id='ddlTest']/option[contains(text(),'Firstname Lastname')]");
driver.FindElement(byXpath).Click();
```